# How do I loop over an array at a given key on an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I was given the assignment to create a function that, given an object and a key,  returns an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given key that are less than 100. I came up with this:

```
function getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var lessThan100 = [];
  var targetedKey = obj[key];
  if (targetedKey === undefined) {
    return [];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < targetedKey.length; i++) {
    if (targetedKey[i] < 100) {
      lessThan100.push(targetedKey[i]);
    }
  }
return lessThan100;
}
```

Now this works, but I am wondering why my original code didn't. I tried to loop over the array at the given property by writing the code below, but it didn't work. Why can't i do this? Also, would someone show me how to clean up this code to make it shorter?

```
for (i = 0; i <obj[key].length; i++) {
    if (obj[key[i]].length < 100) {
      lessThan100.push(obj[key[i]]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `obj[key[i]]` has to be `obj[key][i]`, additionally you check if the *length* is smaller 100 which is probably not your intention.

The whole code could be written as:

```
 const getLessThanHundred = (obj, key) =>
   obj[key].filter(it => it < 100);
```

Comment: Wow. I'm not familiar with that technique yet, but it does work. I am just beginning to learn to code and doing a bootcamp interview training program from hackreactor, so I am still very unfamiliar with javascript. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @sheridan glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your revised code you are checking if the *length* of the item in the array is less than 100, not if the *value* of the item is less than 100. You should be checking the *value* (ie < 100; not .length < 100)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Usually, when I make such an obvious mistake, I catch it after spending some time away from the problem and looking at it again with fresh eyes. I've been going back to this problem every day and I didn't catch that.

Comment: The function is supposed to return an empty array if the property obj[key] does not exist. Do I have to use an if statement for that or is there another way?

Comment: You can new up an empty array, and then push items into it if they exist. At the end, return the array. If nothing was added, you will return the empty array that you newed up.